# How to Create Heat Map from confidence values in a column Objects inside a JSON file ? (go through the image link)

Tags: python, json, pandas, heatmap, jupyterhub

`[{"pageName":"visitutah", "extPostId":1967170976682576484, "rawText":"#SaltLakeCity is a major production hub for some of your favorite flicks like The Sandlot and #Sundance cult classic SLC Punk. #VisitUtah #TheStoryisUtah ?\n?\nPhotos: @jaydashphotography, @20thcenturyfox, @sonypictures",
    "extCreatedAt":"2019-01-29T01:24:36.000Z","postLink":"https://instagram.com/p/BtMy5Stn4pk",
    "metadata":{
      "language":"en",
      "keywords":["production","favorite","slc","classic","punk","cult","hub","flicks","sandlot","major","photos"],
      "hashtags":["saltlakecity","sundance","visitutah","thestoryisutah"],
      "imgWidth":1064,"imgHeight":800,"imageColors":[
        {"value":"#483d8b","confidence":0.15739377611845315,"color":"DarkSlateBlue"},
        {"value":"#4682b4","confidence":0.1250121974502026,"color":"SteelBlue"},
        {"value":"#556b2f","confidence":0.08467575995418002,"color":"DarkOliveGreen"}
      ],
      "imageTags":[
        {"value":"Cityscape","confidence":0.9921912550926208},
        {"value":"Metropolitan area","confidence":0.990021288394928},
        {"value":"City","confidence":0.9872371554374696},
        {"value":"Urban area","confidence":0.9839804172515868},
        {"value":"Metropolis","confidence":0.9772381782531738},
        {"value":"Skyline","confidence":0.9565803408622742},
        {"value":"Aerial photography","confidence":0.9396143555641174},
        {"value":"Skyscraper","confidence":0.9393568634986876},
        {"value":"Human settlement","confidence":0.9386814832687378},
        {"value":"Daytime","confidence":0.9368680119514464}
      ],
      "imageObjects":[
        {"name":"Skyscraper","conf":0.7262023091316223,"vertexes":[
          {"x":500,"y":348},{"x":612,"y":348},{"x":612,"y":505},{"x":500,"y":505}]},
        {"name":"Skyscraper","conf":0.6854296326637268,"vertexes":[
          {"x":642,"y":363},{"x":724,"y":363},{"x":724,"y":512},{"x":642,"y":512}]},
        {"name":"Skyscraper","conf":0.6445878148078918,"vertexes":[
          {"x":705,"y":282},{"x":795,"y":282},{"x":795,"y":430},{"x":705,"y":430}]},
        {"name":"Tree","conf":0.6393409371376038,"vertexes":[
          {"x":659,"y":516},{"x":782,"y":516},{"x":782,"y":603},{"x":659,"y":603}]},
        {"name":"Tower","conf":0.630145251750946,"vertexes":[
          {"x":379,"y":301},{"x":483,"y":301},{"x":483,"y":423},{"x":379,"y":423}]},
        {"name":"Skyscraper","conf":0.621281623840332,"vertexes":[
          {"x":928,"y":308},{"x":1035,"y":308},{"x":1035,"y":603},{"x":928,"y":603}]},
        {"name":"Skyscraper","conf":0.591198742389679,"vertexes":[
          {"x":252,"y":314},{"x":327,"y":314},{"x":327,"y":419},{"x":252,"y":419}]},
        {"name":"Skyscraper","conf":0.5170044302940369,"vertexes":[
          {"x":71,"y":288},{"x":205,"y":288},{"x":205,"y":512},{"x":71,"y":512}]},
        {"name":"Building","conf":0.4679428040981293,"vertexes":[
          {"x":2,"y":575},{"x":72,"y":575},{"x":72,"y":648},{"x":2,"y":648}]},
        {"name":"Tower","conf":0.46002140641212463,"vertexes":[
          {"x":75,"y":280},{"x":206,"y":280},{"x":206,"y":513},{"x":75,"y":513}]},
        {"name":"Skyscraper","conf":0.4523395895957947,"vertexes":[
          {"x":458,"y":299},{"x":505,"y":299},{"x":505,"y":415},{"x":458,"y":415}]},
        {"name":"Tower","conf":0.4486623704433441,"vertexes":[
          {"x":254,"y":312},{"x":322,"y":312},{"x":322,"y":414},{"x":254,"y":414}]},
        {"name":"Skyscraper","conf":0.4317977726459503,"vertexes":[
          {"x":370,"y":302},{"x":492,"y":302},{"x":492,"y":430},{"x":370,"y":430}]},
        {"name":"Tower","conf":0.4043044149875641,"vertexes":[
          {"x":926,"y":308},{"x":1033,"y":308},{"x":1033,"y":585},{"x":926,"y":585}]},
        {"name":"Skyscraper","conf":0.3842355906963349,"vertexes":[
          {"x":901,"y":281},{"x":947,"y":281},{"x":947,"y":353},{"x":901,"y":353}]},
        {"name":"Tower","conf":0.3708430230617523,"vertexes":[
          {"x":506,"y":350},{"x":608,"y":350},{"x":608,"y":497},{"x":506,"y":497}]},
        {"name":"Skyscraper","conf":0.3536655306816101,"vertexes":[
          {"x":850,"y":296},{"x":889,"y":296},{"x":889,"y":374},{"x":850,"y":374}]},
        {"name":"Tower","conf":0.2946276068687439,"vertexes":[
          {"x":706,"y":278},{"x":788,"y":278},{"x":788,"y":421},{"x":706,"y":421}]},
        {"name":"Skyscraper","conf":0.25367069244384766,"vertexes":[
          {"x":0,"y":239},{"x":752,"y":239},{"x":752,"y":800},{"x":0,"y":800}]}
      ],
      "imagePHash":-2256780375582496922},"nFollowers":86200,"nComments":18,"nLikes":1927},
{"pageName":"visitutah","extPostId":1965520773869116669,"rawText":"Winter relaxation at another level. #VisitUtah?\n?\nPhoto: @michellemayfield, #SpanishFork",
    "extCreatedAt":"2019-01-26T18:45:56.000Z","postLink":"https://instagram.com/p/BtG7rrlHpz9",
    "metadata":{
      "language":"en",
      "keywords":["winter","relaxation","level","photo"],
      "hashtags":["visitutah","spanishfork"],
      "imgWidth":1080,"imgHeight":1350,"imageColors":[
        {"value":"#2f4f4f","confidence":0.12358215657201124,"color":"DarkSlateGray"},
        {"value":"#008080","confidence":0.0777761666658871,"color":"Teal"},
        {"value":"#b0c4de","confidence":0.06802374259213351,"color":"LightSteelBlue"}
      ],
      "imageTags":[
        {"value":"Water","confidence":0.8073040843009949},
        {"value":"Art","confidence":0.502187192440033}],
      "imageObjects":[
        {"name":"Tree","conf":0.7405981421470642,"vertexes":[
          {"x":16,"y":56},{"x":965,"y":56},{"x":965,"y":1350},{"x":16,"y":1350}]},
          {"name":"Tree","conf":0.5986928939819336,"vertexes":[
            {"x":953,"y":236},{"x":1077,"y":236},{"x":1077,"y":434},{"x":953,"y":434}]}
          ],
          "imagePHash":-9063616246493099103},"nFollowers":85978,"nComments":160,"nLikes":14462},
{"pageName":"visitutah","extPostId":1964829982460857211,"rawText":"The 2019 #Sundance Film Festival is here! Follow along as we highlight Utah's iconic film locations throughout the Festival`[Visit Utah Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Rlm.jpg)

Guys, There is a JSON File which I am trying to read in Jupyter Hub(Python Environment). I posted earlier but I guess my question was unclear. What I need to do is find a way to isolate the confidence values inside the Column Object and then create a heat correlation map. Could this be done? Could someone just help me isolate the confidence values? Go through the embedded image link. Any kind of suggestions are welcome - numPy or pandas

Thanks.

Comment: Share a sample data, not an image. Provide an expected output too.

Comment: cant help you without minimal information, like complete sampe lot data in column

Comment: how can I share this sample data. Can you point me in the right direction.

Comment: for the future: post a minimal example that demonstrates your problem. If you just dump a bunch of data, people will be scared and do not want to help you :)

Comment: I understand :) let me know if you need more data

Comment: can you provide how you obtained the actual json file?

Comment: it was provided to us by the client